# Batch exporting files from one gdb to another with source file name as exported name

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, feature-layer

Is it possible to batch export these files from one geodatabase (test.gdb) into another and name them as the source file name even though the feature layer name is not the same as the source file name?

[image]

Feature to geodatabase tool in ArcGIS names them as the feature layer name and not the source file name.

Comment: The “file” in your picture is a feature class and does not correspond to a single system file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very easily done in model builder or a simple python script. Suggest you explore the help file on model builder iterators there is a feature class iterator and its output could feed into a Copy or Feature class to Feature Class tool.

Comment: Thank you very much will do